# Using HTMLFormElement.reset() with Downshift and react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, downshift

I'm using DownshiftJS to create an Autocomplete component using the `useCombobox` hook. It's all going well and testing with `react-hook-form`. Unfortunately, I've hit a problem where the reset function available within `react-hook-form`, which fires the `HTMLFormElement.reset()` method, does not trigger any state/input change within the Downshift component.

This means that when a user selects an item from the list (which triggers an event in the `Autocomplete`), clicks the reset button and then clicks the input again, the list is filtered to just the previously selected item. This is because the selected item is stored within a `selectedItem` internal state.

How can I get the reset method to trigger a change within `Autocomplete` component and clear the `selectedItem` state?

I've isolated the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-forms-downshift-reset-g2t4x?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `React.useEffect` to detect if the user hits the reset button and reset the selected items accordingly in your `Autocomplete` component

```js
const [inputItems, setInputItems] = useState(options);
const {
  inputValue,
  ...
} = useCombobox({
  items: inputItems,
  ...
});

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!inputValue) {
    // user resets value. Reset selected option
    setInputItems(options);
  }
}, [inputValue, options, setInputItems]);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64144984/using-htmlformelement-reset-with-downshift-and-react-hook-form]

Comment: Thanks. So this worked because I was concerned about the value within selectedItem when infact, nobody needs to worry about what's in the selectedItem state. The value can be grabbed from inputValue.